# Gradle Sync fails when implementing app module. ':projectpodosample@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app

Tags: android, gradle

When I try to implement my app module in a module called ProjectPodoSample (which consists only of a newly created empty activity), I get those errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':projectpodosample@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':projectpodosample@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':projectpodosample@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':projectpodosample@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':projectpodosample@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app.
```

I tried to delete the module and recreate it. I tried to clean my project and rebuild it. I tried to update my Gradle version in settings.gradle. I tried to uncheck the "Offline work" option. Nothing worked. Here are my two gradle.build files.

gradle.build in app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.visionnaires.projectpodo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

gradle.build in projectpodosample module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.visionnaires.projectpodosample"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':app')

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

I use Android Studio 3.1.2 64-bit.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I decided not to implement the app module. I just moved all the classes I needed to get in my projectpodosample module to another module, then implemented this module into my app module and into my projectpodosample module (and that worked for whatever reason).

I guess you just can't implement the app module.

Hope this was useful.